# wocommerce calculate shipping not being called

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hi have a wocommerce plugin, While changing the payment method. the cost for shipping my function calculate_shipping is not being called. and therefore shipping methods are not updating with appropriate cost

here are some samples from my code.

```
    public function __construct() {
                add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', array($this, 'update_shipping_charges'), 1);
}

public function  update_shipping_charges() {
        // jQuery code
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function () {
                    // Set the select value in a variable
                   
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');

                     //testing
                    $('body').on('updated_checkout', function() {
                        console.log('updated');
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: Is your constructor even called?

Comment: yes, its been called. I am getting the console logs, but the shipping methods ain't updating, but the calculate_shipping isn't getting called.

Comment: Try wrapping everything inside the init hook. Maybe the code gets executed too early.

Comment: like                 add_action('woocommerce_init', array($this, 'update_shipping_charges'),1); ?
inside the constructor right

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping everything inside the init hook. Maybe the code gets executed too early:

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'init_action' ] );
}

public function init_action(): void {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', [ $this, 'update_shipping_charges' ], 1 );
}

public function update_shipping_charges(): void {
    // jQuery code
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ( $ ) {
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function () {
                // Set the select value in a variable
                let body = $( 'body' );

                body.trigger( 'update_checkout' );

                //testing
                body.on( 'updated_checkout', function () {
                    console.log( 'updated' );
                } );
            } );
        })( jQuery );
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

You could try multiple hooks if `init` don't works:

```
woocommerce_loaded
woocommerce_init
plugins_loaded <- I use this one in my plugins for example
```

Comment: add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'init_action' ] );
 this isnt working

Comment: Ok. Try the others first. If they don't work, I need to continue on my dev computer. And be sure that your JS code is correct. Maybe add an alert or something like this to ensure your code get's added.

Comment: i donno why but this isnt' even triggering the console.logs I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following (Add to functions.php or via Code Snippets plugin)

```
function kia_checkout_on_payment_change() {
    wp_add_inline_script( 'wc-checkout', '
        jQuery( document.body ).on( "payment_method_selected", function() {
            jQuery( "form.checkout" ).trigger( "update_checkout", { update_shipping_method: true } );
            console.log("payment selected");
            } );
        '
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kia_checkout_on_payment_change' );
```

A couple notes....

1. We're adding the script right after the `wc-checkout` script is loaded.
2. We're listening for the WooCommerce checkout script's [`payment_method_selected`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f5b3556e14b0b60585b4111bf2872ee69e245ecb/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js#L123) (but yes, it's a core Woo trigger in the checkout) trigger which should fire when the payment method is changed
3. We're explicitly passing some arguments to the `update_checkout` function.

Don't have any shipping methods set up locally to test it properly, but I hope it points you in the right direction.